# bind jQuery contextmenu to select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have `select` element with multiple `option` that I generate dynamically.
I want to assign RMB click on each option, however this always assigns it to the parent or does not assign at all

I tried:

```
$("#my_selector > *").contextmenu(test_f);
$("option").contextmenu(test_f);
$("#my_selector *).contextmenu(test_f);
```

and non of them is working.

if I use just

```
$("#my_selector > *").contextmenu(test_f);
```

then it works just fine but only when I RMB selector itself (drop down is collapsed)
can you please guide me to the right solution

Note:
change event is not what I need.

Comment: Most browsers do not support events on options

Comment: You can do something like `$("option:selected")...`

Comment: give more code pls html + jquery or js

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, here you are: https://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, does not work, I assume this is a sort of limitation

Comment: @epascarello, probably you are right, thanks! then will not spend more time on it..

Comment: @BeliaevMaksim Apologies, I was mistaken.